How to Handle and Return Status When Canceling a Pending Ethereum Transaction in AWS Lambda
I'm working on a system that involves two AWS Lambda functions for managing Ethereum transactions:
Send Transaction Function: Sends an Ethereum transaction.
Cancel Transaction Function: Cancels the original transaction by sending a new transaction with the same nonce but a higher fee.
Here's the problem: When I send the first transaction and then request to cancel it, the transaction is successfully canceled and replaced by the new one. However, the original transaction's status remains pending until it times out, which means it doesn't return anything immediately indicating that it was canceled.
The main issue seems to be with the async function that sends the transaction:
 const tx = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(rawTransaction);


This function does not proceed to the next line or return any error when the transaction is canceled by another transaction.
What I want to achieve is to return a response from the Send Transaction Function as soon as the original transaction is canceled by the cancellation transaction. Currently, it just stays in the pending state until it times out.
How can I implement a mechanism to periodically check the transaction status and return a response indicating that the transaction was canceled, rather than waiting for a timeout?
Thanks,
This is what happens when I cancel a transaction :
when I call the cancel function transaction returns me this which is fine enter image description here
But the return of the original transaction is this enter image description here
enter image description here
